# Disable ascending/descending order in jquery tablesorter only for initial page load

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, tablesorter

I created mvc 4 application , in this application I'm listing down a table

this is view of it

[image]

Each time its listing down ascending order , according to first column value

this is jquery code snippet

```
        $(function () {
        $("#table-hover").tablesorter({ widthFixed: true, sortList: [[0, 0]] })
        .tablesorterPager({ container: $("#pager"), size: $(".pagesize option:selected").val() });
    });
```

I want to disable this ascending/descending feature and keep remain pagination of jquery tablesorter plugin in initial page load

Comment: i dont understand your question, you have the disable code but you want to call it server side, or you dont know how to disable it?

Comment: simply ,remain pagination , disable this ascending/descending feature , in jquery tablesorter

Comment: check this link, i believe it will help http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-options-headers.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need pagination, then you really don't need to use tablesorter. I'm sure asp.net provides a method to add it.

In any case, since you appear to be using the original tablesorter, you could disable every column to prevent sorting as @oMiKey suggests. If you use my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), simply add "sorter-false" to each header cell.

To prevent the initial sort, remove the `sortList: [[0, 0]]` option from the initialization code:

```
$(function () {
    $("#table-hover")
        .tablesorter({
            widthFixed: true
        })
        .tablesorterPager({
            container: $("#pager"),
            size: $(".pagesize option:selected").val()
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

to disable the first sort, add class "nosort" to each table header and add this code to your jquery:

```
$('table.tablesorter').each(function (i, e) {
    var myHeaders = {}
    $(this).find('th.nosort').each(function (i, e) {
        myHeaders[$(this).index()] = { sorter: false };
    });

    $(this).tablesorter({ widgets: ['zebra'], headers: myHeaders });
});   
$('.nosort').toggleClass('nosort');
```